# Replacement for "GradleVersion.current()" with Gradle v6?

Tags: gradle

Updating a legacy project from gradle 3 to 6 and it seems that `GradleVersion.current()` was removed around v5.

I've searched here and google and haven't found a replacement. What's an easy way for me to check the user's version within `build.gradle`?

Comment: Can you try this in your build.gradle logger.lifecycle("$gradle.gradleVersion")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the Gradle version with `project.getGradle().getGradleVersion()`. API reference:

- [Project.getGradle()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getGradle--)
- [Gradle.getGradleVersion()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getGradleVersion--)

The following example task will print the version using the above API

```
task printGradleVersion {
    doLast {
        println project.gradle.gradleVersion
    }
}
```